# Burn normal bootloader onto Atmega328P configured to use internal 8MHz clock

Tags: atmega328, bootloader

I have an Atmega328P that I have previously burned with a bootloader configured to use the 8MHz internal clock as described [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoToBreadboard). I would like to now burn the normal Duemilanove bootloader configured to use an external 16MHz clock onto the chip. However, when I try following the normal procedure, it says "Invalid device signature". I can still upload programs to the chip and they will run, but I would like it to use the 16MHz external clock. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a [sketch that will upload the Optiboot bootloader](http://www.gammon.com.au/bootloader) - that will work perfectly well on the Duemilanove.

The latest version will be available on [GitHub](https://github.com/nickgammon/arduino_sketches).

This particular sketch is in the "Atmega_Board_Programmer" subdirectory.

You need to run this sketch on another Arduino (like a Uno) and connect it up like this:

[image: Programming bootloader]

Comment: As it turns out, I had the chip in backwards. It surprisingly still works.

Comment: No wonder you got invalid device signature! :)